# web service is returning null data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

The status code is 200 but the data is not returned. When I get status the output printed by data is

OS_dispatch_data: data[0x60000046b080] = { leaf, size = 53, buf = 0x600000674580 }

This when data is out and json object is deserialized its showning the following data dictionary

```
{
    message = "Some input field missing";
    status = 406;
}
```

This is my code

```
NSError *error;

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"xxx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:120.0];

    NSMutableDictionary * mapData=[NSMutableDictionary new];

        [mapData setObject: [Crs_sharedvariable sharedMySingleton].crs_country forKey:@"country_name"];

    [mapData setObject:[Crs_sharedvariable sharedMySingleton].crs_userId forKey:@"user_id"];

    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSLog(@"%@",[[request URL]absoluteString]);
    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSLog(@"error %@",error);
            NSLog(@"data %@",data);
            NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@", json );
            NSLog(@"%@", [json valueForKey:@"message"]);

        });

    }];
```

Comment: User AFNetworking library.
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: It looks like your backend is returning errors using custom JSON body, rather then indicating them with http status codes. Is this incosistent with their documentation? Or did I miss the point in your question?

Comment: Try `NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];` because it should be useless to use the pretty printed. Also, error is nil ? You didn't check. your server is saying that there is an issue with your data. Check the doc.